# How to connect to a router without the security key?

Tags: router

If the label on the router indicating the security key is missing, is there a way to find the security key or to connect to the router without it?

Comment: A factory reset is probably the only way. Google "factory reset *routername*"

Comment: @nifle a factory reset will revert the password to the one shown on the label which is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Without the original label you cannot do what you want to do. If your router has wired ethernet, then use a wired connection to access the admin page. The default password will be in the manual. Once on the admin page you will be able to insert a new security key.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is inacurite wich key are you looking.

There is a few situations:

1. Lost Wireless Key. You can do factory reset and google for default key.
2. Lost Admin page key. Usualy when you try to acces your admin page an you cancel login form then page shows default password and username.
3. If above doesn't work you can install NON-STOCK firmware like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) through "emergency room". Wich give more functions and completely resets router wireless key to none.

I hope my answer helped you.